# Run a jar file using scheduled powershell and validate the result

Tags: java, powershell, windows-services, pgp

I am stuck in a scenario where I need to run a jar file which decrypts an encrypted file on regular interval from a particular directory on a windows server. Anyone can help in powershell which executes the jar file ?

I use the following command to run the jar file using command prompt and it works fine on local machine.

```
java -cp PGPDecrypt.jar pgpDecryptPackage.PGPDecrypt C:\Users\anirudgu\Desktop\abcd\TestFile.pgp C:\Users\anirudgu\Desktop\abcd\anirudguprivatekey.asc C:\Users\anirudgu\Desktop\abcd\outputfile.txt Passcode
```

This jar takes 4 parameters as input

1. File Path of encrypted file
2. File path of private key
3. File path where we need to put the output i.e. decrypted file
4. The passphase

The output of the is basically a string : *File decrypted successfully and placed at location : C:\Users\anirudgu\Desktop\abcd\outputfile.txt*

Can someone please suggest on the powershell side ?

Comment: What is the problem with writing the script and why not a .bat (Windows batch) script?

Comment: That's my idea of using powershell. I am open to accept alternate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in powershell:

```
cmd.exe /c 'java -cp PGPDecrypt.jar pgpDecryptPackage.PGPDecrypt C:\Users\anirudgu\Desktop\abcd\TestFile.pgp C:\Users\anirudgu\Desktop\abcd\anirudguprivatekey.asc C:\Users\anirudgu\Desktop\abcd\outputfile.txt Passcode'
```

The '/C' argument, executes a cmd session and then terminates.

For creating a scheduled script:

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler

Comment: Thank you soo much Vish.
I just wanted to check if I can store the file paths as a variable also, which is calculated at run time as the latest file needs to be picked up by the script.
I have tried this but when i store the values in variable and pass it to the above command will it work ?
Sorry for these lame questions but a noob at powershell.

Comment: Don't worry about the questions, ask as many as you want. 
You can do this:

$test_file   = 'path';

$private_key = 'path';

$output_file = 'path';

cmd.exe /c "'java -cp PGPDecrypt.jar pgpDecryptPackage.PGPDecrypt $test_file $private_key $output_file Passcode'"

The main java command is wrapped using this format: " + ' + var_name + ' + "